# highcharts: epoch time not properly connected to Xaxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When i have inconsistent data coming in (when for example the server that gathers the data is down) highcharts does not plot the X correctly.
It still plots like there is data on the X while there is not.
It should afcouse plot the correct hour when there actually is data.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVwFK/
Data variable is inconsistant!

Can someone show me how i can correct this error?

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline',
            margin: [50,130,90,100]
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Weather Today'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'test'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%H:%M'
            },
            tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '10px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature C'
            },
            opposite: false,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0
            }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Humidity %'
            },
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: true
            }, {
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Air Pressure hPa',
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            },
        }],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    if(this.series.name === 'Temperature')
                    {
                        return ''+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M',this.x) +': '+ this.y + ' C';
                    }
                    if(this.series.name === 'Humidity')
                    {
                        return ''+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M',this.x) +': '+ this.y + ' %';
                    }
                    if(this.series.name === 'Air Pressure')
                    {
                        return ''+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M',this.x) +': '+ this.y + ' hPa';
                    }
            }
        }, 
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                lineWidth: 4,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 3
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            symbol: 'circle',
                            radius: 3,
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        series: [{
                name: 'Temperature',
                data: temp,
                type: 'spline',
                /* yAxis: 0, */
                shadow: true,
                showInLegend: true, 
                pointInterval: 60 * 1000, 
                /* pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 1),*/
                dashStyle: 'solid',  
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                } 
                } , {
                name: 'Humidity',
                data: hum,
                yAxis: 1,
                shadow: false,
                showInLegend: true,
                pointInterval: 60 * 1000,
                type: 'line',
                dashStyle: 'dot',  
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                } 
                }, {
                name: 'Air Pressure',
                data: bar,
                yAxis: 2,
                shadow: false,
                showInLegend: true,
                pointInterval: 60 * 1000,
                type: 'line',
                dashStyle: 'shortdot',  
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                } 
        }],
        navigation: {
            menuItemStyle: {
                fontSize: '6px'
            }
        } 
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of specifying time data for Highcharts and I think you are using the wrong way for the problem. It's the second style you should use when having gaps in the data.

1. A compact array without gaps only containing the values for each time-point

   ```
   data: [2, 5, 3, 6, 1]
   ```

   Then you specify the time-point for the first measure together with the interval. eg:

   ```
   pointStart: Date.UTC(2013,1,12), // start point in milliseconds
   pointInterval: 3600 // interval in milliseconds
   ```

   You cannot have different length between the time-points this way.
2. A two dimensional array with both time-points and measure

   ```
   data: [[Date.UTC(2013,1,12), 2],
          [Date.UTC(2013,1,12), 5],
          [Date.UTC(2013,1,12), 3],
         ...]
   ```

   This way of specifying the array can have gaps where there's no data.

See the reference [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data)
and example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-arrays-datetime/).